# Why does the submit button just reload my page instead of sending the information?

Tags: php, html, button, input, submit

When I press the submit button the page reloads but doesn't send me to the "upload.inc.php" file. After clicking the submit button I just arrive at the index.php file without anything happend.

I copied the code and tried the html part in another file and there it worked. Therefore the mistake has to be somewhere in the rest of the index.php file. I added already echo's in the beginning of the "upload.inc.php" file and it didn't change a thing. Thus the error is somewhere in the index.php file but I don't find it. I appriciate your help! I searched for 4-5 hours and didn't find it.. .

Index.php (html part)

```
      <form action="includes/upload.inc.php" method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
      <input type='file' name='file'>
      <input type='hidden' name='userId' value="<?php echo $id; ?>" >
      <button type='submit' name='submit'>UPLOAD</button>
      </form>
```

Index.php (full file)

```
      <?php          
          require "header.php";
          require "includes/dbh.inc.php";
      ?>
        <main>
    <?php
          if (isset($_GET['login'])) {
            //Login Bereich der Hilfe suchenden
              if ($_GET['login'] == "successHelpSeeker") {
                echo "<p> Hello help seeker. </p>";


              }
              //Login Bereich der Helfenden
              elseif ($_GET['login'] == "successHelper") {
                echo "<p> Hello Helper.</p>";
              }
              //Login Bereich für beide gleich
                //Profilbild
              $id = $_SESSION['userId'];

            $sqlImg = "SELECT * FROM profileimg WHERE userid='$id'";
    $resultImg = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlImg);
    $rowImg = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultImg); 
      echo "<div>";
      //existiert schon ein Profilbild? bei 0 ja bei 1 nein
        if ($rowImg['status'] == 0) {
          echo "<img src='uploads/profile".$id.".jpg'>";
        } else{
          echo "<img src='uploads/profiledefault.jpg'>";
        }
        echo "<p>".$row['userid']."</p>";

      echo "</div>";

                //enctype specifies how the form data should be encoded --> ?>
   <form action="includes/upload.inc.php" method='enctype='multipart/form-data'>
        <input type='file' name='file'>
        <input type='hidden' name='userId' value="<?php echo $id; ?>" >
        <button type='submit' name='submit'>UPLOAD</button>
        </form> 
        <?php      
            }




if(isset($_SESSION['userId'])){
    echo '<p>You are logged in!!</p>';
}
else{
    echo '<p>You are logged out!</p>';
}
?>

         </main>
```

normally it should send the choosen file to the upload.inc.php file but it just reloads the page without sending the information.

Thanks a lot for your help!

upload.inc.php :

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    require 'dbh.inc.php';
    $id = $_POST['userId'];


    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $file = $_FILES['file'];

        $fileName = $file['name'];
        $fileTmpName = $file['tmp_name'];
        $fileSize = $file['size'];
        $fileError = $file['error'];
        $fielType = $file['type'];

        $fileExt = explode('.', $fileName);
        $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

    $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png');

    if (in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)) {
        if ($fileError === 0) {
            if ($fileSize < 10000000) {
                $fileNameNew = "profile".$id.".".$fileActualExt;
                $fileDestination = '../uploads/'.$fileNameNew;
                move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination);
            $sql = "UPDATE profilimg SET status=0 WHERE userid= '$id';";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

                header("Location: ../index.php?uploadsuccess");
            }


            } else {
        echo "Your file is too big. Please upload a file which isn't bigger than 10 mb.";
            }
        } else {
            echo "There was an error uploading your file.";
        }


        } else {
            echo "Please upload only jpg, jpeg, png or pdf files.";
        }
```

The crazy thing is, I changed the "action" to a new file with barely something in it. Still the submit button doesn't send me to the new file and just reloads the page. Could it be a problem which has to do with the sessions I'm working with? :O

Comment: Your HTML code at the PHP part is incorrect, `method='enctype='multipart/form-data'`, method is missing, it is typo?

Comment: I can't see any way this would fail to submit to `includes/upload.inc.php`. Perhaps `includes/upload.inc.php` redirects back to `index.php` … but you didn't include the code for that. Create a [mcve] to track down where the problem is - something simple the just outputs a static string to start with, then build on that.

Comment: Thanks for this idea. I will create an example to track down the mistake! Anyway, I added the code of my upload.inc.php file. When I find the mistake I'll update my post.

Answer (score -1):

Look in your index.php page **method='enctype='mltipart/form-data'**

```
  <form action="includes/upload.inc.php" method='enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <input type='file' name='file'>
    <input type='hidden' name='userId' value="<?php echo $id; ?>" >
    <button type='submit' name='submit'>UPLOAD</button>
  </form> 
    <?php      
        }
```

Comment: While that is an error, it would cause the page to submit a GET request to `includes/upload.inc.php`. That doesn't explain the behaviour the question is asking about.

Comment: Change `method='enctype='multipart/form-data' ` to `method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'`

Comment: Thanks for your help. The method was a typo which happend while copying the code. Therefore it was right in my original code. I'll add the code of my upload.inc.php file and maybe there's the mistake. Thanks again for your help.